# Diode for 200v charging of ev battery module

Tags: diodes, lithium-ion, charger

Im attempting to use a DC power supply to charge a 200v battery module.

I realise the power supply is not "smart" and I do not plan on fully charging the module. Long story short, I just need to raise the charge level a bit so that another smart charger can take over.

My power supply puts out up to 300v, 6 amps.

Upon connecting the battery to the power supply (still turned off), two 250v/10A fuses that I had on + and - blew.

I think in order to proceed, I need a diode on the positive? I ordered these (https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B079KBP5CN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), and while the specs seem to line up, I could use some reassurance as this is new territory for me.

Will one of these diodes on the positive do the job? Should I be looking for a different type? Thanks.

Comment: Put a lamp in series with the battery to limit current, and power up the supply _before_ connecting it to the battery. _"I just need to raise the charge level a bit so that another smart charger can take over."_ - why?

Comment: Toasters make good current limiters too.  not a diode

Comment: Listen to Polynomial. And think : if the smart charger doesn't want to touch it, it probably has a good reason. Don't be dumber than the charger.

Comment: Why do I need a current limiter? The output of the power supply (max 6A) is very very low compared to the pack size. I can also lower that output if needed. I'm not saying it's wrong advice, I just want to understand more. I assumed the problem was the battery energy entering the charger instead of the other way around. 
@BruceAbbott, The in car charger is mad about an imbalance that I am correcting. The pack is not anywhere near empty or anything like that. Half the pack was added after build and is is at a lower soc.

Comment: I have seen some 200v loads like the one below, so if I need some sort of load in the circuit maybe I can use one of them. I'm still not exactly sure how that would work. I start the load in series, start the power supply at nominal voltage, connect the circuit...and then leave the load running? 

https://www.amazon.com/MakerHawk-Electronic-Adjustable-Intelligent-Resistance/dp/B07F3NHHST/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=180w+200v+load&qid=1577743918&refinements=p_85%3A2470955011&rnid=2470954011&rps=1&sr=8-5

Comment: Actually, it seems like simply starting the power supply first avoids fuse blowing. Thanks all! I'm charging, albeit very very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT DO THIS.**

You cannot simply attach a DC power supply to an automotive battery like this to charge it. Doing so is exceedingly dangerous and you could start a serious fire that cannot be easily put out with a conventional fire extinguisher. 200V is also more than enough to do you some serious harm, either in terms of electric shock or burns from a short.

These batteries are intended to be charged by a proper charge controller that regulates the charge voltage and current while monitoring the battery voltage and internal temperature. The proper chargers also include a heap of safety features that a simple DC power supply will not have.

If the battery voltage has dropped below the safe minimum level for charging, take the battery to an EV specialist. They can advise you on how to proceed with your specific model, and will likely have the correct equipment to safely restore the battery (or test if it is indeed safely restorable).

Comment: For those who want [Video Evidence](https://youtu.be/WdDi1haA71Q?t=178).

Comment: Actually you can, and you can safely. It's obviously not the best way, but it's also no where near impossible. But thanks for the obligatory "ignore the question and yell safety".